# Urls change whenever a menu item is selected

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I have three menu items with identical menus. When you are on the index site the menus work as they are supposed to. But as soon as you visit the other pages the urls change to:

Users: `/pages/forms/pages/forms/users.html`
Customers: `pages/forms/pages/tables/customers.html`

Do any of you know how can I remove the duplicates that seem to happen?

```
       <div class="menu">
            <ul class="list">
                <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
                    <a href="index.html">
                        <i class="material-icons">home</i>
                        <span>Home</span>
                    </a>
                 <li>
                    <a href="pages/tables/customers.html">
                        <i class="material-icons">view_list</i>
                        <span>Customers</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href="pages/forms/users.html">
                        <li class="active">
                        <i class="material-icons">assignment</i>
                        <span>Users</span>
                    </a>
                    </li>
                </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this you can make the paths relative to the root folder of the domain by prefixing them with `/`, for example:

```
<a href="/pages/tables/customers.html">
```

Comment: Thank you, but that would mean I would need to have full links relative to root each time and since its something that will be tossed around I need another work-around.

Comment: You should be doing this by default. It's the standard way of creating links. If you make them relative to the current folder then should you change any page in the site you'll have to remember to update all the links.

Answer (score 0):

There is minor problem in your code just use like this.

```
<a href="/pages/tables/customers.html">
  <i class="material-icons">view_list</i>
  <span>Customers</span>
</a>
```